# Add two backgrounds in menu li using html/css/javascript

Tags: html, css

I have this menu to which I need to add a background like this:

```
http://faraon.al/faraon/hover.jpg
```

This comes when a user hovers over the menu.

My issue is, I can make the blue+yellow part, but that little half circle I have no idea how to insert it.
Any help would be appreciated!
I used smth like this:

```
menu ul li{
    background-image: url(images/bgtop.png), url(images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}
```

I saw that you could add two backgrounds to a single place, but it didn't work the way I needed for me.

Thanks

Comment: In what way did it not work. Did it only show one of the backgrounds? Can you post the two source images?

Comment: the issue is, i can't overlap the half circle above the other image..
i mean, what i reached to do was putting the two of them together, but not one on top and one behind..

Comment: Can you provide links to the two images?

Comment: wel, it's simple, i mean, in normal condition, the li has grey color, in hover it must have that blue+yellow and the half circle in the middle

Comment: Why don't you use a single image which has the half circle?

Comment: Because, the width of the li can variate!
I can't use a single image, anyways, i solved it :)
I added a background color, then a border for the yellow top, and an image to the center..

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
menu ul li:hover {
    background-image: url(images/bgtop.png), url(images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center, top left;
}
```

Comment: Well, it's supposed to be an image which i should repeat, i can't give the li a fixed image, can i?

Comment: So, what exactly are you looking for? The `li` should look like the image when user hovers?

Comment: You want the `li` to show one image normally, and another image on hover, right?

Comment: yes, the li should look like the image, in normal state the li has grey background, on hover i need the blue+yellow background with the half circle in the middle..